¿Es posible crear un usuario en SQLServer con el que se pueda acceder a la información de una base de datos pero que no pueda loguearse al management?
Tengo una base de datos DB_XYZ de prueba donde los datos son alumnos, cursos y notas.
Creé un usuario user_colegio para que pueda acceder a la base de datos.
El punto es que deseo saber si es posible configurar el usuario mencionado para que no pueda acceder al management pero sí pueda acceder a la base de datos a través de su programación en visual studio y pueda crear, eliminar o actualizar registros.
He intentado con
Deny connect sql to [user_colegio] y Alter login [user_colegio] disable;

lo cual no le permite acceder al management, pero no funcionan los reportes de prueba en visual studio 2022

Quiero saber si existe alguna manera de crear un usuario en SQL Server que tenga permisos para consultar, eliminar, actualizar los registros pero que no pueda hacer un login al management del sql.

No entiendo el sentido de que el usuario pueda ver las tablas, pero no pueda verlas desde una ide en particular... tal vez el problema sea otro?

Yo entiendo el sinsentido PERO hay clientes que piden ese tipo de cosas como en este caso desean que el proramador pueda desarrollar y hacer uso de la base de datos pero sin tener acceso o mejor dicho al management.

Una posible opción es crear un trigger de logon, en el cual valides el usuario y el programa que usa para conectarse. Sin embargo, esta opción podría ser fácil de deshabilitar o permitir acceso por medio de otros programas que tengan capacidades similares a SSMS.
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER DenySSMSAccess ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON 
AS 
BEGIN
    IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = N'user_colegio'
    AND EXISTS(
            SELECT *
            FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
            WHERE program_name LIKE '%Management Studio%'
            AND session_id = @@SPID)
        ROLLBACK;
END;


si quisiera añadir a mas usuarios por deicr que sean user_colegio y user_colegio_dos haria este cambio IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() in ('user_colegio', ''user_colegio_dos ) y deberia funcionar igual? o ese trigger solo funciona para un usuario?

Puede funcionar para la cantidad de usuarios que sean necesarios. Se pueden incluir los usuarios en una tabla para que sea más fácil controlarlos. También podrías generar un log insertando intentos en una tabla.

¿Ya tienes un usuario creado a nivel de la base de datos, con permisos de lectura y escritura, pero sin acceso a nivel de servidor mediante el comando DENY CONNECT SQL? Si no es así, puedes crear un usuario de este tipo. Esto permitirá que el usuario acceda y modifique la base de datos desde una aplicación como Visual Studio (usando una cadena de conexión), pero evitará que pueda iniciar sesión en SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Para otorgarle permisos adecuados, puedes asignarle roles como db_datareader y db_datawriter para que pueda consultar, actualizar y eliminar registros según lo que necesites.
De esta forma, mantienes control total sobre el acceso y las acciones del usuario, limitando su interacción solo a la base de datos y a través de la aplicación.

Claro asi esta definido pero el problema es que yo hacia pruebas desde el visual estudio con esta cadena  de conexion "options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-VOFKR4H; Database=DB_XYZ; User Id=user_colegio;Password=123456;TrustServerCertificate=true;")" el usuario perfectamente no accede al managemente PERO la informacion que genera mi reporte en visual deja de funcionar y sale ese error.

Revisar [answer], saludos.
